# CURL with HTTP2, yum install

Tags: linux, curl

I'm running Redhat 7.2 and I was trying to install latest CURL to support HTTP2 on it.

I installed OpenSSL 1.0.2g by manually. I installed curl 7.48 by YUM. Also I installed nghttp2 1.7.1 by YUM. Now I cannot get curl to support HTTP2.

curl --version
curl 7.48.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.48.0 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.32 libpsl/0.7.0 (+libicu/50.1.2) libssh2/1.7.0
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz UnixSockets Metalink PSL

Tried to build with source code for curl but failed with configuration for ssl and nghttp2 with all the ways from Internet.

./configure --prefix=/usr/bin --with-ssl=/usr/bin --with-nghttp2

configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl:

curl version:     7.48.0
  Host setup:       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Install prefix:   /usr/bin
  Compiler:         gcc
  SSL support:      no      (--with-{ssl,gnutls,nss,polarssl,mbedtls,cyassl,axtls,winssl,darwinssl} )
  SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
  zlib support:     no      (--with-zlib)
  GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
  TLS-SRP support:  no      (--enable-tls-srp)
  resolver:         default (--enable-ares / --enable-threaded-resolver)
  IPv6 support:     enabled
  Unix sockets support: enabled
  IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn,winidn})
  Build libcurl:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  enabled
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  ca cert path:     no
  ca fallback:      no
  LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
  LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
  RTSP support:     enabled
  RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
  metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
  PSL support:      no      (libpsl not found)
  HTTP2 support:    disabled (--with-nghttp2)
  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP GOPHER HTTP IMAP POP3 RTSP SMTP TELNET TFTP

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ubuntu has same issue ... solution first do   sudo apt-get install libnghttp2-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem a while back.  I built nghttp2 from source, rather than using yum so you may or may not need to also install the nghttp2-devel package if it exists because cURL will need the header files as well and it will try to dynamically link to it.

What I had to do to get cURL to recognize nghttp2 was to add some flags (nghttp2 install prefix is `/opt/lamp`):

```
CPPFLAGS='/opt/lamp/include' LDFLAGS='-L/opt/lamp/lib' \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/lamp/lib' \
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-nghttp2=/opt/lamp
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. I made it work by having to reinstall openssl, nghttp2, curl from source.